# Read & Write File in android

Tags: java, android, file

I have an ordinary class java `SvmPredict`within my android project   contain a method that take Two files

as parameter read from the first an write in the second

```
    public class SvmPredict {

    public void run (File input, File output);

   }
```

`SvmPredict.run()` use the java ordinary method to read & write files into the local

project

In other hand ; My activity `PredectionActivity` will instanciate this class `SvmPredict`

and use it

Is this a correct method because it doesn't work ?I don't know the reason

Should I transfomr `SvmPredict` to an android activity? and how in this case i could read

an write into files?

Answer (score 0):

use this class file :

```
import java.io.File;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

public class FileCreation 
{
    String fileName ;
    private File file;

    public FileCreation ( String fileName )
    {
        this.fileName = fileName ;
    }

    public File fileCreationMethod ()
    {
        try
        {
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + fileName );
            if ( file.exists() )
            {
                file.delete() ;
            }
            else
            {
                file.createNewFile() ;
                Log.i(file.getAbsolutePath(),"tushar:filepath_hello") ;
            }
            if ( !file.exists() )
            {
                file.createNewFile() ;
                Log.i(file.getAbsolutePath(),"tushar:filepath_hello") ;
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception err )
        {
            Log.i("Error in file creation","tushar:Exception:fileCreation") ;
        }

        return file ;
    }

}
```

and provide two permissions in android-manifest file .

```
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: you should post some of the basic code from the file. In case the link broke.

Comment: Now , i will take care of it .

Comment: @TusharPandey what is the role of this class and what does this instruction mean   `Log.i(file.getAbsolutePath(),"tushar:filepath_hello");`

Comment: Log.i : is same as : System.out.println() in java .
file.getAbsolutePath() : is used to getting the exact path of file , in your mobile device .
tushar:filepath_hello : is text . 

see this images : https://www.dropbox.com/s/hmru1fijzn00nvy/logcat.png

Comment: thanks for this explanation but i still don't understand how to use above class to read and write files

Comment: Sorry for late response : FileCreation classname = new FileCreation ("filename") ;